# (Python selenium)Getting past Steam's age check

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new at program and web scraping. I want to write a program that visits some best selling games and extracts reviews content, but when it tries to visit M rated games, my program just gets redirected to the age check page.
Therefore, I use selenium to click some buttons so that I can past the age check.

This is the example:

```
IDlist = ['730','1085660']
chrome = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
for i in IDlist:
    url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/app/%s/reviews/?l=english&browsefilter=toprated&snr=1_5_100010_' %i
    chrome.get(url)

    #the age check page                   
    chrome.find_element_by_css_selector('#ViewAllForApp').click()
    chrome.find_element_by_css_selector('#age_gate_btn_continue').click()                                    
    
    for x in range(1,5):
        chrome.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
        time.sleep(2)    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(chrome.page_source, 'html.parser')
       .
       .
       .
```

The first game (ID=730) is work but the problem is when I visit second game (ID=1085660), it's without the age check page and the following error message like this:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#ViewAllForApp"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

How can I avoid this problem? `if-else`?
Or try others methods to past the age check?(ex. add `cookies`)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Steam's age check, you should be able to set the cookie

`lastagecheckage` to `1-0-1900` at `path=/`;

`birthtime` to `-2211667760` at `path=/`;

and

`wants_mature_content` to `1` at the app's path, or /

prior to visiting the store page, or when initializing whichever HTTP library you're using, to effectively bypass the age check redirect.

Don't disregard the paths, they're important. Not setting them could lead you into an infinite redirect loop.

For testing:

```
document.cookie = "wants_mature_content=1"; 
document.cookie = "lastagecheckage=1-0-1900; path=/"; 
document.cookie = "birthtime=-2211667760; path=/";
```

In your browser's JavaScript console at, for example, `https://store.steampowered.com/app/271590/` (GTA V)

You can experiment with the `lastagecheckage` and `birthtime` cookies by going into incognito and looking at the cookies in the application, or network tab in the debug environment on an age restricted title. These should work, though.